# Is it possible to inline Web_UI components?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a habit of taking things to the extreme...

I also like the idea of wrapping structural sections of the site in custom semantic wrappers.

So when I started building web_ui components I ended up with something like this in my main entry page:

```
<x-container_fluid>
  <x-header_fluid>
    <x-site_header>
    </x-site_header>
  </x-header_fluid>
    <x-old_browser>
    </x-old_browser>

    <x-home>
    </x-home>

  <x-footer_fluid>
    <x-site_footer>
    </x-site_footer>
  </x-footer_fluid>
</x-container_fluid>
```

This works like a charm with the one exception being that on each page load the time lapse between 'Page Load' and 'Content Load' causes the browser to flash white until the controls render.

I 'think' my only option is to back off the dime a bit and move the structural bits back into the root page and instead add 'loading...' type placeholders anywhere there is a control that requires render/init cycles.

I'm wondering if there is any way (opt in?) to get the components to compile their templates into the hosting page at build time?

Any and all suggestions welcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is any way (opt in?) to get the components to compile their templates into the hosting page at build time?

Not sure if this is going to give you exactly what you need but it is a very interesting lazy-loading technique that just may help:

http://googlecode.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-reducing.html
http://jsperf.com/stripoutcommentblock

Tom

Comment: I'm working on setting up a base page template to load first prior to script launch now.  Thanks for the links!